# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException android

Tags: android, listview, indexoutofboundsexception

I am having ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in my android app when i go back from a detail item to the item list. It works perfectly when i click any item in the list to view its details but when i go back from the details, any selected item gives this error:

```
12-27 12:40:14.033: WARN/System.err(681): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
12-27 12:40:14.083: WARN/System.err(681):     at com.salesforce.android.restsample.ContactListView$1.onItemClick(ContactListView.java:74)
12-27 12:40:14.083: WARN/System.err(681):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
12-27 12:40:14.134: WARN/System.err(681):     at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)
12-27 12:40:14.134: WARN/System.err(681):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1812)
12-27 12:40:14.153: WARN/System.err(681):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-27 12:40:14.183: WARN/System.err(681):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-27 12:40:14.183: WARN/System.err(681):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-27 12:40:14.193: WARN/System.err(681):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-27 12:40:14.193: WARN/System.err(681):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-27 12:40:14.213: WARN/System.err(681):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-27 12:40:14.213: WARN/System.err(681):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-27 12:40:14.223: WARN/System.err(681):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-27 12:40:14.323: WARN/System.err(681):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The error occurs in my code at this point:

```
        gs.setSelectedAccount(gs.getAccounts()[position]);
```

Here position gives the correct value but the error persists.

Here is the Code:

```
public class ContactListView extends ListActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  GlobalState gs = (GlobalState) getApplication();

  setContentView(R.layout.newlist);

  getAccountData();
  setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, gs.getAccountNames()));

  ListView lv = getListView();
  lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

  final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
        GlobalState gs = (GlobalState) getApplication();
        try{
        gs.setSelectedAccount(gs.getAccounts()[position]);
        }catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JSONObject acct = gs.getSelectedAccount();
        String str = null;
        try {
            str = acct.getString("AccountId")!= "null"?acct.getString("AccountId"):"";
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
            launchAccountDetail(str);
      // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  });


  final Button btnGo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGo);
  Button btnSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
  btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        et.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnGo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
  });

  btnGo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String txt = et.getText().toString();
            launchPartularAccount(txt);
//          getAccountData(txt);
//              setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, gs.getAccountNames()));
        }
      });

  Button newBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnFromDate);
  newBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        GlobalState gs = (GlobalState) getApplication();
        gs.setSelectedAccount(gs.getAccounts()[0]);
        launchAddAccount();
    }

  });
}

protected void launchAddAccount() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, AddAccount.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
protected void launchAccountDetail(String str) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, ContactDetail.class);
    i.putExtra("Id", str);
    startActivity(i);
}

private void getAccountData() {
    GlobalState globalState = (GlobalState) getApplication();

    OAuthTokens myTokens = globalState.getAccessTokens();

    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
    String url = myTokens.get_instance_url() + "/services/data/v20.0/query/?q=";
    String soqlQuery = "Select Id, Name, Birthdate, AssistantName, AssistantPhone, Department, Email, LastActivityDate, AccountId, Account.Name, Account.BillingState From Contact limit 20";
    try
    {
        url += URLEncoder.encode(soqlQuery, "UTF-8");
    }
    catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){}

    HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);

    getRequest.addHeader("Authorization", "OAuth " + myTokens.get_access_token());

    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);

        String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()); 

        JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(result).nextValue();

        JSONArray records = object.getJSONArray("records");

        globalState.setAccountNames(new String[records.length()]);
        globalState.setAccounts(new JSONObject[records.length()]);

        for (int i=0;i<records.length();i++) {
            JSONObject record = (JSONObject) records.get(i);
            String accountName = record.getString("Name");
            globalState.getAccountNames()[i] = accountName;
            globalState.getAccounts()[i] = record;
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   

}
private void launchPartularAccount(String txt) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent i = new Intent(this, ParticularAccount.class);
    i.putExtra("id", txt);
    startActivity(i);   
}
}
```

Comment: can u post your code which throws this error? It might be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend adding in a line of code so you can analyze the array and make sure it isn't change between running.  It might be that when you are bouncing between activities the object is somehow lost or changed.  First of all insure that gs is not null before your call then add

```
ListArray<?> = gs.getAccounts();
```

before you select the account (fill in ? for whatever type of array it is).  See what array it returns or if it possibly returns a null pointer.  That will hopefully get you some more answers

Answer (score 1):

Array out of bound exception will occur if the array size is zero or if the array size is 6 if you try to access 7th index this error will come.

Do one thing i think you are filling the array in listview first time. So vefore filling that array try to clear that array then fill the values.

Comment: But it works perfectly the first time around, but not when i go back and do it again. And clearing the array doesnt work as well, gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Array Index Out Of Bound Occure When You Are accesing an element whose index is greater than your array size... So be care full for that.

Comment: Ranjit Mishra - would it run even the first time if that were the case? Because as i said earlier, it runs the first time around, but when i go back and try to access any contact, then it shows that error.

Comment: I can have better suggestion,If you will post the logcat.

Comment: the log cat is posted in the question